# What is device initialization?

Tags: initialization, device

what exactly is the process of device initialization? In programming we initialize variables by assigning them some initial value. but what is the need to initialize a device in the first place and what values to initialize it with?

Comment: Depends on the device. Question needs more information to be meaningful - what kind of device are you talking about?

Comment: Or: Maybe you are talking about device driver initialization, of which device initialization might be a part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device initialization is doing whatever steps are required to bring a device into a working state. It has got little to do with variable initialization. The process is specific for every device, there are no magic values that would initialize any device that you come across.

Comment: The useful distinction here is that it tends to be a sequence of actions in which the computer provides configuration data to the device, sometimes sequencing it from a reset state to a particular usable state.   The initiaization sequence is not only device dependent, but on the desired configuration of the device for the intended purpose.

Comment: Yeah, generally speaking: Many devices can be seen as a finite state machine, and the driver is the software model for the state with an internal representation of the state the device is in. The device initialization sets the device to a well-defined initial state so the software model can be considered to be in-synch with that device state.

Answer (score 1):

Device initialisation is exactly what it sounds like, preparing a device for use.

For example, when booting a PC, you may need to initialise the keyboard device to make it ready to accept keystrokes from the user.

Operating systems will tend to perform this activity on all devices they detect, hard drives, CD-ROMS, keyboard, video devices and so on, to bring them to a useful state for later use.

Comment: Another example from older days is to send a "reset" escape sequence to a line printer upon initialization to make sure bold is off, etc., so the software can be sure that the next "bold toggle" sequence will toggle bold printing ON.